# Hiding an error message div with setTimeout not working using Smarty

Tags: php, javascript, smarty

I'm trying to hide an error message div using a javascript function setTimeout after a specified time but it gives me errors that its a wrong smarty syntax, i've never used smarty before so i would really appreciate it if anyone can help me get up to speed with this syntax

My code is as follows

> ```
> {if $error_message != ""}
>   <script type="text/javascript">
>     setTimeout(function(){$('error').hide(); }, 1000);
>   </script>
>   <div id="error" class='error_message'>
>     {$error_message}
>   </div>
> {/if}
> ```

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you post the actual error you are getting?

Comment: The error message that i get is as follows Kieran

Fatal error: Smarty error: [in C:/xampp/htdocs/www_google_ads_integration//modules/order_checkout/tpl/order_checkout.tpl line 21]: syntax error: unrecognized tag: $('error').hide(); (Smarty_Compiler.class.php, line 446) in C:\xampp\htdocs\www_google_ads_integration\lib\smarty-2.6.26\libs\Smarty.class.php on line 1094

Answer (score 2):

You will need to make use of `literal` tag of smarty for javascript. It tells smarty compiler not to execute the code and keep as it is.

http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal

for your scenerio,
try,

```
{literal}
    <script type="text/javascript">
        setTimeout(function(){$('error').hide(); }, 1000);
      </script>
{/literal}
```

Comment: There's also `{ldelim}` and the (useless) `{rdelim}`.

Comment: Hi Nik,

i've used the literal tag and it removed the error message however the initial goal is not yet accomplished since it does not want to hide the div at all..:(, any idea what might be going wrong?

Comment: @Donald: As 'error' is id , you should use $('#error').hide(); and not $('error').hide();

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use Smarty reserved characters such as { and } elsewhere in the template like with inline JS, you have to use the literal-tag to escape it. Also, if you have some whitespace around it smarty realises it is not a smarty tag and ignores it.

See http://www.smarty.net/docs/en/language.function.literal.tpl